# OnPause return NullPointerException when screen is turned off

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `TextView` correctly initialized in my `Activity`.
I can use it in the code without any problems. In the `onPause()` method, I use `myTextView.setText("");`. It works fine if I press home button or I start a new `Activity`, but when I use the power button to power off the screen I get a `NullPointerException` thrown by the `setText()` line.

I guess that my class members are reset to null by the power off event before `onPause()` is called. 
Which is the correct way to handle this case?

Should I catch the broadcast `SCREEN_OFF` or is there something wrong in my code?

My code is as simple as

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    myTextView.setText("");
    super.onPause();
}
```

Logcat output

```
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): Process: com.myapp, PID: 6717
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at com.myapp.MyActivity.onPause(MyActivity.java:35)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5335)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
03-04 19:58:44.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6717):     ... 11 more
```

And here is how I initialize my `TextView`

```
private TextView myTextView;
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //new AsyncTask
    //onPostExecute(){
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //}}.execute();
}
```

I know it is initialized inside an `AsyncTask`, but I can definitely use it during `Activity` lifecycle. I have some `Button` that if clicked change its text and they work, also `onPause()` works. This only happens when screen is turned off...

**UPDATE:**
For some weird reason when I press the power button my `Activity` performs `onPause()` as expected, then `onResume()` and `onPause()` an instant later. What can cause this?

Comment: can you post logcat output ? the textview is not nulled when onPause() is called..

Comment: post the full activity code

Comment: @Deacoy it only happens when screen is turned off.

Comment: Post the full activity code, please. Do you have any code that sets myTextView to null anywhere?

Comment: @BVB It's 1000 lines of code and there's no line where I set to null the `TextView`

Comment: You need to call `super.onResume()` from `onResume()`. Also, try moving the line that sets `myTextView` to `onCreate()` of the `Activity`.

Comment: @BVB read my last edit. I forgot to write `super.onResume()` but I call it. Everything works fine till i switch my screen off.

Comment: if you add `if (myTextView == null) continue;` before .setText the application still crash?

Comment: Move `myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` to `onCreate()` in your activity.

Comment: @BVB just found the cause and answered myself to the question.

Comment: `I guess that my class members are reset to null by the power off event before onPause() is called`.  Impossible.  In general, you should not update the UI in onPause() or onStop(). Why are you trying to do that anyway, since the activity is going to the background?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue here is that you didn't call `super.onPause()` first in the method and got a `SuperNotCalledException`.

You want something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myTextView.setText("");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the log and where `myTextView` is assigned to get more help then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in the answer to [this][1] question. 
The screen lock was recreating my `Activity` in portrait mode, because it's Android default behavior after screen is locked. 
Calling `onResume` and `onPause` right after, caused the `NullPointerException` because the `AsyncTask` had not finished doing his work.

So I solved this issue by simply checking that the values are not null (not yet initialized)

Comment: This is not necessarily good practice. Please read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: In this case there are no side effects. Application only works in landscape mode and no resource/data needs to be manually handled. Checking for screen off and consequently do nothing is also a bad practice, because oncreate and onresume are called while screen is still black so I'd get `NullPointerException` right after unlocking screen.

Comment: This is not the point.  There are many reasons other than these why your activity can be recreated.  All you are doing is hiding the bugs.  The correct answer is to fix the bugs, code the life cycle methods correctly and **remove** `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`.  It's nothing more than a hack.  If you continue down this route, you will have bugs in your app that you may or may not discover in testing.  e.g. Run your app as it is now then call yourself.  Does it crash?  Most likely it will, especially if your app is in the background when the phone rings.

Comment: @Simon I replaced that, I now check for values not being null.